# Botón de favoritos en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Sé que para este problema necesito hacer algún `ToggleButton` y colocarlo en un ítem de la `RecyclerView`.

¿Como hago que al clickear el botón, este ítem pase a una `Activity`, junto con los demas ítems, cuyo `ToggleButton` fue clickeado, y que al clickear de nuevo el `ToggleButton` dentro de la `Activity`.

Este se elimine de la lista? en otras palabras más simples,

¿Como hago una `Activity` de favoritos con items de una `RecyclerView`?

Aquí hay un ejemplo claro de lo que pregunto: [RecyclerView and Shared Preferences](https://github.com/MFaisalHyder/RecylerView-And-SharedPreferences), pero necesito que alguien me explique como funciona.

Comment: Bueno te voy a contar la realidad eso simplemente es una coleccion de favoritos y se lo pasa por intent o la manera que veas. La mayoria de las App te dicen agregado a favorito pero si ers rapido con tus dedos cerrando la app no te la agrega a favoritos en la base de datos, cuando la abres de nuevo. La idea es simplenete decirle que se agrego mientras en background se esta agregando puedes hacer una cola de tareas de agregar a la base de datos o blokear el boton , firebase es muy rapido 1 seg es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Hola gusto en saludarte.

ok en primer lugar debes agregar un boton en el `layout` de tu fila ( layout de cada elemento de la lista).

Dentro de tu `adapter` , localiza el metodo donde le das valores a las filas de ese `RecyclerView`, que si usas el `RecyclerView.Adapter`, seria el metodo `OnBindViewHolder` y alli asignas un `OnClickListener` para ese boton y guardas en las preferencias que esa fila se agrego a favoritos , alli tambien podrias colocar que cuando de click vaya a una nueva `activity`.

En tu nueva activity se crearia un nuevo adapter y un nuevo onclicklistener y en el metodo onclick en este caso eliminarias esa fila de las preferencias.

Con esto siempre tendrias que filas han sido agregadas a favoritos y cuales no.